# is there any difference in load time for /images/img.jpg vs //domain.com/images/img.jpg vs http://domain.com/images/img.jpg

Tags: image, content-management-system

We had an issue with our navigation menu images not using HTTPS on an otherwise secure Contact page (sporadically) and I suggested changing the path and removing the protocol and domain name so the images would load without any further issue, since the developer working on the problem had trouble reproducing it. He removed the protocol but left the domain name intact, which will also work, but it brought up a question that I've been wondering about for awhile and not being able to find a definitive answer. My question: is there any difference in load time for a file where the path is `/images/img.jpg` vs `//domain.com/images/img.jpg` vs `http://domain.com/images/img.jpg`.

I'm leaning towards the first one possibly being faster since it might not have to do a domain lookup, but I honestly don't know, which is what brought me here...